# Objective C, getting nan in NSLog

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nan

I am trying to get time between 2 points in time. I don't know what am I doing wrong but my NSLog gives me result of "nan". Total time was: nan seconds. If I remove [timer start] and [timer stop] from if statements then it gives me normal result in double.

```
- (void) filterFrequency {

Timer *timer = [[Timer alloc] init];
if (self.currentFrequency > 2000 && pointInTime % 2 == 0)

{
    [timer startTimer];
    pointInTime = pointInTime + 1;
}
 else if (self.currentFrequency > 2000 && pointInTime % 2 == 1)

{
    [timer stopTimer];
    pointInTime = pointInTime + 1;
    NSLog(@"Total time was: %f seconds", [timer timeElapsedInSeconds]);

}
```

Here is Timer.h
    #import

```
@interface Timer : NSObject {
NSDate *start;
NSDate *end;
}

- (void) startTimer;
- (void) stopTimer;
- (double) timeElapsedInSeconds;
- (double) timeElapsedInMilliseconds;
- (double) timeElapsedInMinutes;

@end
```

Timer.m

```
#import "Timer.h"
#import "ListenerViewController.h"

@implementation Timer

- (id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    start = nil;
    end = nil;
}
return self;
}

- (void) startTimer {
start = [NSDate date];
}

- (void) stopTimer {
end = [NSDate date];
}

- (double) timeElapsedInSeconds {
return [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
}

- (double) timeElapsedInMilliseconds {
return [self timeElapsedInSeconds] * 1000.0f;
}

- (double) timeElapsedInMinutes {
return [self timeElapsedInSeconds] / 60.0f;
}

@end
```

Comment: What is "Timer"?  That's not a standard Objective-C component.

Comment: What does `timeElapsedInSeconds` return?

Comment: - (double) timeElapsedInSeconds {
    return [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
}

Comment: Your `start` date is probably `nil`.

Comment: The code doesn't look right; it looks like this method is supposed to be called frequently but you allocate a new `Timer` object each time? That would mean that if timeElapsedInSeconds is supposed to subtract end time from start time then it won't work as the timer has never been started.

Comment: @trojanfoe nailed it, I think.  The timer you "stop" has never been started, because you allocate a new one with each call.

Comment: wow...never would have seen it...let me try it...but thanks!

Comment: Thank you trojanfoe, it doesn't shows nan anymore.however it still doesn't show right time, it shows 0 seconds all the time.

Comment: Perhaps you are calling the method too quickly to allow a difference in time to be measured.  You don't say how frequently you call `filterFrequency` but you will start it one iteration and stop it on the next; it's possible that's too quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use following code to measure the time a sound needs to load. I don't know what you wanna do in your code (and why) but this one is surely useful for exact time measurement.

```
    // Setup:

    uint64_t tm_start,tm_end,tm_elapsed,tm_nanoSeconds,tm_milliSeconds,tm_seconds;
    mach_timebase_info_data_t info;

    // Start:
    tm_start = mach_absolute_time();    

    // do your stuff 

    // Example
    NSSound *cocoaAudioPlayerSound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:mediaLocation byReference:YES];
    // … time flies


    // End:
    tm_end = mach_absolute_time();
    tm_elapsed = tm_end - tm_start;
    mach_timebase_info(&info); 
    tm_nanoSeconds = tm_elapsed * info.numer / info.denom;
    tm_milliSeconds = tm_nanoSeconds / (1000000);
    tm_seconds = (tm_milliSeconds/1000);

#ifdef DEBUG
    fflush(stdout);
    printf ( "| allocateAudio: %5lld milliseconds (%5lld seconds) (%12lld nano seconds)\n", tm_milliSeconds, tm_seconds, tm_nanoSeconds );
#endif
```

Comment: thanks DigiMonk. where do i put this code? do you maybe have a sample code? thanks anyway

Comment: @user2035902 in above code you would prepare with //Setup, the time consuming work after //do your stuff (here //Example) and when your don'e you do the //End stuff. So this example is kinda 'inline' but easy to implement in your own way.

Comment: @user2035902 Cool. Your'e welcome. & You can always accept the answer :)

Comment: Sorry didnt know about this accepting feature, i am new to this :)

Comment: FYI forgot to mention that one must "#include <mach/mach.h>" and "#include <mach/mach_time.h>"